# If P, Q are invertible matrix, show the following Moore Penrose inequality $(PAQ)^+ \neq Q^{-1}A^+P^{-1}$ with a counterexample.

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples, inverse, generalized-inverse

If P, Q are invertible matrix, show the following Moore Penrose inequality $(PAQ)^+ \neq Q^{-1}A^+P^{-1}$ with a counterexample.

$A^+$ is the Moore Penrose Inverse.

I have tried many examples but I can't seem to find a countereaxample. How should I proceed?

Comment: How about $P = [3, -7; -2, 5]$ and $Q = [1, -8;9, 6]$ and $A = [7, 0; 3, 0]$?

Comment: @RiverLi How do you find this example? Is there any systematic way to find this?

Comment: I used matlab to generate random matrices with integer entries.